# How to download Nessus agent using wget using license accept option in Amazon Linux or Redhat machine

Tags: linux, wget, nessus

I want to download Nessus agent from the Nessus downloads page. But I am unable to directly download due to the License Agreement option in Nessus page

Below command only partly downloaded the file
wget  --no-check-certificate --post-data='accept="I accept the terms of this license"&x=""&sid=5mcia8gchg28attkc9oarah153&p=NessusAgent-7.4.2-amzn.x86_64.rpm' 'https://www.tenable.com/downloads/nessus-agents' -O NessusAgent-7.4.2-amzn.x86_64.rpm

While installing I get below error
rpm -ivh NessusAgent-8.2.2-amzn.x86_64.rpm
error: NessusAgent-8.2.2-amzn.x86_64.rpm: not an rpm package (or package manifest):

This seems to be due to the package being partly downloaded as the download size is less than 1 mb but actual file is 16 MB

Answer (score 1):

wget -O NessusAgent-10.1.1-ubuntu1110_amd64.deb https://www.tenable.com/downloads/api/v1/public/pages/nessus-agents/downloads/15882/download?i_agree_to_tenable_license_agreement=true

if you need any other package, such as .rpm just grab the file name from their website:

https://www.tenable.com/downloads/nessus?loginAttempted=true

What I did is I downloaded the file with a regular download thru my browser and went to Downloads in the browser, copied the url and pasted it.

For instance, if you need .rpm file,  I just tested it, link changes to 15800 sub dir: https://www.tenable.com/downloads/api/v1/public/pages/nessus/downloads/15800/download?i_agree_to_tenable_license_agreement=true

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate this is quite an old post but the only way I have managed to do this so far is to grab the file on desktop and upload to S3/GitHub and download it from there using wget. I haven't found a better way as yet.